# WiX ExePackage: Failed to send request to URL

Tags: download, wix, burn

Using WiX Burn v3.7.1224, I failed acquiring a remote payload through ExePackage. I usually succeed with similar ExePackage elements so I suppose the problem may be related to the specific URL I'm trying to download.

This specific "exe URL" is http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe

To be precise: the interactive page is at http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe and clicking there on the download anchor "seems" to result in the direct "exe URL" listed above. I say "seems" because I had to dive into the page source code to find out the final "exe URL", and this may be a problem.

Here is the WiX fragment of interest:

```
<Fragment>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="TesseractLookup"
                         Variable="TESSERACT_REGVALUE"
                         Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\Tesseract-OCR" 
                         Value="CurrentVersion" />   

    <PackageGroup Id="Tesseract">
        <ExePackage Compressed="no" 
                    PerMachine="yes" 
                    Permanent="yes" 
                    Vital="yes" 
                    Name="redist\tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe"                    
                    InstallCondition="NOT TESSERACT_REGVALUE"
                    DetectCondition="TESSERACT_REGVALUE"
                    DownloadUrl="http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe">

            <RemotePayload Description="Tesseract-OCR - open source OCR engine" 
                           Hash="35C61604AAAC961C24CD28F959566B2E39244541" 
                           ProductName="Tesseract-OCR" 
                           Size="13525781"
                           Version="3.02.02.0" />
        </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>        
</Fragment>
```

I succeeded with the browsers I tried (Firefox and Internet Explorer) and with a basic "wget" command as well, in a matter of seconds. But failed with Burn.
All were provided with the same "exe URL".
I even tried with disabled firewall and anti-virus softwares just in case, but to no avail.

Do you have any hint about what might be happening?

Here are the relevant lines from the install log:

```
[27F8:1FE8][2013-03-07T08:36:46]w343: Prompt for source of package: tesseract_ocr_setup_3.02.02.exe, payload: tesseract_ocr_setup_3.02.02.exe, path: D:\soft\audiveris\dist\redist\tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe
[27F8:1FE8][2013-03-07T08:36:46]i338: Acquiring package: tesseract_ocr_setup_3.02.02.exe, payload: tesseract_ocr_setup_3.02.02.exe, download from: http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe
[27F8:1FE8][2013-03-07T08:36:47]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to send request to URL: http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe
[27F8:1FE8][2013-03-07T08:36:47]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to connect to URL: http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe
[27F8:1FE8][2013-03-07T08:36:47]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to get size and time for URL: http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe
[27F8:1FE8][2013-03-07T08:36:47]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed attempt to download URL: 'http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe' to: 'C:\Users\herve\AppData\Local\Temp\{7715fbb6-5bc5-442f-86a0-655fa082bd7d}\tesseract_ocr_setup_3.02.02.exe'
[27F8:1FE8][2013-03-07T08:36:47]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to acquire payload from: 'http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe' to working path: 'C:\Users\herve\AppData\Local\Temp\{7715fbb6-5bc5-442f-86a0-655fa082bd7d}\tesseract_ocr_setup_3.02.02.exe'
```

Comment: The error code suggests the server is returning 404. Try using Fiddler to see what the HTTP request looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Following Rob suggestion (Thanks!), I installed and investigated with Fiddler. The HTTP request is actually a HEAD request and server is returning 404.

I pulled another software from another site, still with Burn, in order to discover what Fiddler should see: It's a HEAD request followed by a GET request.
This makes sense: To my limited knowledge, HEAD is like a GET but with no content returned, and is used primarily for adjustments before launching the actual transfer.

Then, going back to Tesseract site, I forged with Fiddler a brand new HEAD request as follows:

```
HEAD http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Burn
Host: tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

Response was: "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" (just like the response to initial Burn request)

I then forged a GET request (just replacing "HEAD" by "GET"):

```
GET http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Burn
Host: tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

And this time, I got: "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", followed by the 13525781 bytes of content... BINGO!

So now, we are left with:

1. How can a server respond 404 to a HEAD request but correctly respond to the similar GET request?
2. If Tesseract Google site has problems with HEAD requests, is there a way to tell Burn to skip the HEAD request and proceed directly with a GET request?
3. Any other fix?

Comment: I just found this is a bug in Google Project Hosting. See http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=HEAD&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=660 This bug has remained unfixed for 5 years now, so I'm not confident in a quick fix! @Rob: Isn't there any way to bypass the HEAD request in Burn?

Comment: I know that a simple "wget" could do the job. Problem is that there is no such wget or similar utility on Windows (given that I'd like to support all Windows versions since Windows XP). Should I embed a basic "wget binary" in the WiX bundle itself and use this binary at installation time? Is there any WiX/Burn example available somewhere?

Comment: Responding with 404 to HEAD and handling GET at the same time is one of best practices that maintainers of web servers implement for security reasons. Wix should not fail to download just because HEAD returned 404.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that should get fixed in v4.0 - https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6331.